# vue2 plus vee-validate - how to customize error messages without ES6?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying (without a success) to customize error messages for vee-validate, but all the examples on the website use ES6. I can bet it's doable also without it, so any suggestions what I am doing wrong are appreciated :)

```
<script>
    const messages = {
      en: {
        confirmed: "Your password is not confirmed",
        email: "I really dont like your email"
      }
    };

    Vue.use(VeeValidate);
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'            
    });
    app.$validator.updateDictionary(messages);
</script>
```

There are no errors, simply the default messages are used.

**UPDATE**

Below is my HTML code.

```
<input type="text" name="email" v-validate data-vv-rules="required|email" />
<span v-show="errors.has('email')">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>

<input type="password" name="password" v-validate data-vv-rules="required" />
<span v-show="errors.has('password')">{{ errors.first('confirmation')}} </span>  
<input type="password" name="confirmation" v-validate data-vv-rules="confirmed:password"/>
<span v-show="errors.has('confirmation')">{{ errors.first('confirmation')}}/span>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`() =>`  is syntax to define function in [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies), so to convert syntax of vee-validate to older Javascript.

so from the [documentation](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/rules#custom-messages):

```
alpha: () => 'Some English Message'
```

will be equivalent of

```
alpha: function() {
  return 'Some English Message'
}
```

Similarly, you have to make following changes:

```
<script>
    const messages = {
      en: {
        confirmed: function () { 
            return "Your password is not confirmed"
        },
        email: function () { 
            return "I really dont like your email"
        }
      }
    };

    Vue.use(VeeValidate);
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'            
    });
    app.$validator.updateDictionary(messages);
</script>
```

### Updated Answer with working example

There seems to be some syntax errors in the above code, Following is the working code with latest [vee-validate syntax](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/rules#custom-messages):

```
<script>
const dictionary = {
  en: {
    messages: {
      confirmed: function () { 
        return "Your password is not confirmed"
      },
      email: function () { 
        return "I really dont like your email"
      }
    }
  }
};

VeeValidate.Validator.updateDictionary(dictionary);
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
Vue.config.debug = true;
var App = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
</script>
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2yvcLm3/).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Now what makes me wonder is that I still get the default error messages from vee-validate. I've attached the HTML code for reference, maybe there is something else I do incorrectly?